# How to remove the weight attribute?

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I'm running into a problem. I want to remove the weight attribute from the front-end of my Magento webshop, but it keeps telling me that the attribute is reserved by system.

> The attribute code 'weight' is reserved by system. Please try another attribute code

I have tried multiple options to make it a normal attribute

1. Changing is_user_defined in table eav_attribute in the database to 1 (http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-delete-system-attribute/)
2. Edit in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml `<weight><external>1</external><required>1</required></weight>` to `<weight><external>1</external><required>0</required></weight>` (http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/21975/)

Is there another solution?

Comment: This is not an answer, more of a recommendation. Do not remove system attributes. http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/14837/146. You can get into a lot of trouble if you do.

Comment: I'm aware of that, that's why I want it disabled for the frontend, so it won't show up on the product pages.

Comment: Removing system attributes will be the beginning of the end in mucking around with Magento. I guarantee you will only do it once, on a live website, you will contemplate the void. Did you try setting all the following properties on the weight attribute to NO? --> Visible on Product View Page on Front-end, Used in Product Listing, Used for Sorting in Product Listing

Answer (score 2):

This is for those of you who wish to make it so that there are no system attributes.

1. If you go to the screen where you can drag and drop your attributes (Manage Attribute Set) you will notice that the address bar looks something like this “.com/index.php/admin/catalog_product_set/edit/id/4/”.
2. Now go to your php myadmin panel and browse the table called “eav_attribute” the entity_type_id column will have the id number of the attribute set you are using (see above).
3. If you open all entries with the id number you will see a entry called “is_user_defined” if you change that to a “1” (from a “0") it will make it a “non -system attribute” and you can do anything you want with it.